# why is ubuntu incorrectly detecting my graphics card?

Tags: graphics, ati, radeon, gpu, 16.04

So in my ubuntu I was using the latest mesa drivers from the ppa. I also had the amdgpu and radeon xorg drivers installed. I was running a 16.04 gnome version of ubuntu. Maybe I am reading the terminal output wrong also, but my r9 390 has 8GB of memory and ubuntu doesnt seem to be reporting that.

ubuntu is not installed at the moment since I had to reinstall windows to make sure it just wasnt some issue with the card I never noticed.

why does my card show up as a 290 in linux (incorrect) and a 390 in windows (correct)?

[image: Windows 7]

[image: Ubuntu 16.04]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first update the PCI ID database on Ubuntu by running `sudo update-pciids` in a terminal to see if this helps to correct the name.

From the latest database snapshot:

```
1002  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
    67b0  Hawaii XT [Radeon R9 290X]
        1043 046a  R9 290X DirectCU II
        1043 046c  R9 290X DirectCU II OC
        1043 0474  Matrix R9 290X Platinum
        1043 0476  ARES III
        1458 227c  R9 290X WindForce 3X OC
        1458 2281  R9 290X WindForce 3X OC
        1458 228c  R9 290X WindForce 3X
        1458 228d  R9 290X WindForce 3X OC
        1458 2290  R9 290X WindForce 3X
        1458 22c1  Grenada PRO [Radeon R9 390]
```

It looks like that the Radeon R9 390 is only specific to a card with `1458 22c1` as its subclass ID, you can check the ID of your card with `lspci -nnv`

This lookup table is maintained by the community, if the information is not correct, you can make changes here: http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/

Comment: hmmm... i dont imagine those numbers changing from one OS to the other but i will definitely try it when i get ubuntu reinstalled. right now though windows shows me the "hardware id" is: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_67B1&SUBSYS_2358148C&REV80

Comment: 1002:67b1 simply points to Radeon R2 390, it will be great to add this entry to the database.

Comment: that helps to explain why it might be showing up wrong! if i look up the 67b1 part it only comes up as a r9 290. i have put in the "add item" request as you suggested so that this could possibly get corrected.