# Fixing Incorrect GPU Detection

Tags: 16.04, lspci

I have tried to install both 14.04 and 16.04 on the computer in question; i'm going with 16.04 because my GPU is theoretically supported by AMDGPU drivers but there's a problem;

Running `lspci -nnv` gives me the following:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus LE [Radeon HD 8830M] [1002:682b] (rev 87) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Venus LE [Radeon HD 8830M] [1462:3012]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at dfe00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at dfe40000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

The GPU in question is not a Radeon HD 8830M, but an MSI R7 250, a desktop card.

I have seen this thread: [why is ubuntu incorrectly detecting my graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758880/why-is-ubuntu-incorrectly-detecting-my-graphics-card?newreg=1ad0182606cb44b0ac16dbc5032a979a)

But aside from suggesting how the database might be updated, I dont know that I can resolve the issue? How can I manually override this entry? Is that possible? Is that nessecary?

If I proceed with installing AMDGPU drivers with the incorrect hardware listing in lspci it seems like that would cause problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run `update-pciids` and try again

Comment: Already did that boyo